# localhost address created in nextjs db.json

Tags: next.js13

```js
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import "./globals.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


// export const metadata = {
//   title: "Web tutorials",
//   description: "Generated by doyi",
// };

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const [topics, setTopics] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:9999/topics/')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setTopics(result);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <h1>
          <Link href="/">WEB</Link>
        </h1>

        <ol>
          {topics.map((topic)=>{
            return <li key={topic.id}><Link href={`/read/${topic.id}`}>{topic.title}</Link></li>
          })}
        </ol>
        {children}
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link href="/create/">Create</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/update/1">Update</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="button" value="delete" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbrOQ.jpg)

I used nextjs version 13 app router.

npx json-server --port 9999 --watch db.json After creating the db.json file with this code, I am trying to create a data and load the newly created data using fetch.

The created address http://localhost:9999/topics is accessible at first, but after a while it says the web page cannot be found and an error keeps appearing when you try to use the fetch code.

It still doesn't work, so if I delete the db.json file and go back to the address given by typing the code above, I can connect again, but the same problem keeps repeating over time.

I have written the process of error occurrence and hope that the error is resolved.